# vue build without overidding NODE_ENV

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, vue-cli

I want to have the ability to run `yarn build` with the `development` and `production` mode, so I have created `.env` file and add the variable `NODE_ENV=development`, but when I run `yarn build` Vue override it. Is there some workaround for that?? Probably I can use some other variable, like CUSTOM_ENV, but it's odd that I can't control the default env variable in a way I want to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

okay, I found the solution, I can use my `.env` variables in the package.json:

```
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --mode %NODE_ENV%",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build  --mode %NODE_ENV%",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint  --mode %NODE_ENV%",
```

so now no matter what kind of build I'll use it will use my env variable, without overriding it